# How can I use a fixed effects on age without having panel data?

Tags: dataset, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

I have a dataset consisting of a case group and a control group, each with 8,000 unique individuals. Among the various independent variables, age is also included for each individual. However, I am not interested in age per se; I simply want to use it as a control variable. I have been advised to control for age using fixed effects instead of performing a regression with age group dummies. How should I proceed with this approach? My data is not panel data, and I have only one observation for each individual. I am using Stata as my software. I have searched online for an answer to my question and reviewed similar queries, but I haven't found enough information that fully addresses my question. Thank you! Best regards, Mijhalov